# How to use Rest Api in app Flask for insert data to Database?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I have a app `Flask`. I want to use `Rest api` for insert data to Database. I have a `app.py`file and `api.py` file. I want to write a `post` method in `api.py`. I want to get information from client using `add.html` file and post it to `api`. then `api` this information add to Database. I use `pyodbc` for connect to SQL Server Database.in this Database, there is a table `tbl_product` with columns `P_ID`,`title`,`count`,`price` and `active`. I don't know, how do it. When I run `python api.py` on `http://localhost:5000/add`, I see `{ "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."}`. Also, When I run `python app.py`, on `http://localhost:8080/add`I see `Method Not Allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL` .
 Can you help me?

my `app.py` file is:

```
 from flask import Flask,render_template,url_for, request, redirect, flash, jsonify,json
 import pyodbc
 import requests
 from api import ProductAdd

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.secret_key= "flash_message"


 # creating connection Object which will contain SQL Server Connection
 conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                  'Server=TABRIZIYAN;'
                  'Database=market_DB;'
                  'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
 cursor = conn.cursor() 

@app.route('/add')
def add(): 
    if request.method =='POST':
        productDetails= request.form
        title= productDetails['title']
        count=productDetails['count']
        price= productDetails['price']
        active= productDetails['active']
        create_row_data = { 'title':str(title), 'count':str(count), 
                            'price':str(price), 'active':str(active) }
        info = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/add', data= create_row_data) 
        return info.text   #return(render_template('product.html'))
    else:
        return (render_template('add.html'))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port="8080")
```

my `api.py` file is:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,url_for, redirect, flash
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource
from flask import jsonify
import pyodbc
import requests

 flask_app = Flask(__name__)
 api = Api(app=flask_app)

 class ProductAdd(Resource):
     def post(self): 
          productDetails= request.json
          title= productDetails['title']
          count=productDetails['count']
          price= productDetails['price']
          active= productDetails['active']
          cursor = conn.cursor()
          cursor.execute(" INSERT INTO Tbl_product(title, count, price, active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) 
                         ",(title,count,price,active))
          conn.commit()
          resp = jsonify('User added successfully!')
          resp.status_code = 200
          return resp

api.add_resource(ProductAdd , '/add')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify what your actual issue is. "Am I doing it right?" is too vague for us to understand what exactly you need help with

Comment: change ```@app.route('/add')``` to ```@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])